# GetContext() не работает

Tags: jquery, canvas, javascript

подскажите пожалуйста почему [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/uHjrd/) не получается залить область окна браузера чёрным цветом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
starCanvas = $('#starCanvas')
```

jQuery возвращает свой объект, а не элемент. Чтобы получить элемент этого объекта, нужно написать следующим образом:

```
starCanvas = $('#starCanvas')[0];
```

Comment: спасибо. а скажите ещё пожалуйста ы чем отличие jq-объекта от js-объекта.

получается, что js-объект это просто элемент. а d jq-объекте элемент это только первое свойство(с индексом 0), но кроме него есть ещё свойства какие то. так?

Comment: jQuery всегда возвращает коллекцию (like Array) элементов, даже если вы ищите по ID.

Comment: понятно. спасибо